# Weekly Revenue for a Calendar Year, Monday-Sunday

Tags: sql, r, ms-access, rstudio

I am trying to find weekly revenue for a company. However, I am defining weekly, in this case, as Monday-Sunday. The existing table is sorted by transaction, so there are multiple entries per day that need to be combined in to weekly gross revenue.

The categories in the table are:

year
month
day
employeeID
TransactionRevenue

Since I am starting with the year 2013, January 1st is on a Tuesday. How can I create a script in R that will allow me to pull weekly info with a week defined as Monday through Sunday? Alternatively, is there a way to do this using SQL?

Comment: You might find "bizdays package"  useful

Comment: You could solve the problem a bunch of ways. In SQL this could be done by adding the week and year columns to your dataset. T-SQL Datepart function makes that easy. Then you could GROUP BY WEEK AND YEAR.

Comment: Here is an example

        WITH BASE AS (
            SELECT  transaction_date, 
     amount, 
     DATEPART(WEEK,transaction_date) as transaction_week,
     DATEPART(YEAR,transaction_date) as transaction_year
    FROM TRANSACTIONS)

    SELECT SUM(amount) as revenue,
           transaction_week,
           transaction_month
    FROM   BASE

    GROUP BY
           transaction_week,
           transaction_month

Comment: @jcwrequests - MS Access SQL does not support CTE window functions.

Comment: You may find the `ISOweek` package useful.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can run an aggregate SQL query for weekly totals and specify what day to start the week using MS Access' [DatePart()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DatePart-Function-26868a79-5505-4e5a-8905-6001372223fa) function. However, first you need to use [DateSerial()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateSerial-Function-a0128476-83a0-407c-831a-93f2b046f503) to bind the year, month, day values into an actual date:

```sql
SELECT DatePart('ww', DateSerial(t.[year], t.[month], t.[day]), 2) As WeekNumber, 
       SUM(t.TransactionRevenue) As WeeklyRevenue
FROM Table1 t 
GROUP BY DatePart('ww', DateSerial(t.[year], t.[month], t.[day]), 2)
```